# CSS layout: Is it possible to move the div box?

Tags: html, css, layout

[Demonstration of the website's frame](http://frame-1043.appspot.com)

Hi all, is it possible to move the aqua div box which is div 'tags? There are two ideal places to put it. One place is above the div 'article' inside the div 'wrapper'. The other place is alongside the div 'article'. This really drives me crazy. Please help. Many thanks. 
**HTML:**

```
<header>Header{width:100%;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

    <nav>nav{max-width:960px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

    </nav>
</header>
<div id="wrapper">wrapper{max-width:960px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

    <article>article{max-width:960px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px; margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

        <div id="post_info">post_info{max-width:660px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

        </div>
        <div id="post_content">post_content{max-width:660px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

        </div>
        <div id="text_divider">text_divider{max-width:670px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

        </div>
    </article>
    <div id="pagination">pagination{max-width:680px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

    </div>
    <div id="tags">tags{max-width:960px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

    </div>
    <footer>footer{} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

    </footer>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
 header, nav, #wrapper, article, #post_info, #post_content, #text_divider, #pagination, #tags, footer {
     border: 1px solid;
     padding: 20px;
     margin: 20px auto;
 }
 span {
     color: white;
 }
 header {
     width:100%;
 }
 nav {
     max-width:960px;
 }
 #wrapper {
     max-width:960px;
 }
 article {
     max-width:960px;
 }
 #post_info {
     max-width:660px;
 }
 #post_content {
     max-width:660px;
 }
 #text_divider {
     max-width:670px;
 }
 #pagination {
     max-width:680px;
 }
 #tags {
     max-width:960px;
     background-color: aqua;
 }
 #tags span {
     color: aqua;
 }
```

Comment: Can you show us the HTML ? It will be really helpful.

Comment: Hi Lauromine, do you know how can I add HTML after post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using following css to place the 'aqua' div above the 'article' div --

```
.wrapper { position: relative; }
#tags { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
.article { margin-top: 140px; } /*margin amount to be the height of aqua div*/
```

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. The div 'tags' was not above div 'article'.

Comment: ahh, its `#wrapper` to be in css at first line instead of `.wrapper`...do like this -- `#wrapper { position: relative; `....it will work now.

Comment: for some reason you will have to add `border-top: 1px solid transparent;` css to `#wrapper`...then adding top margin will push only article div. Or setting `overflow`, `auto / hidden` also resolves this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really helps.

Comment: Hi Ravi, could you do me another favor? I don't quite understand the reason behind your solutions. Why does it work?

Comment: For this, I think this article may help you --  [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)

Answer (score 0):

`Aqua` div above the `article`:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/61sxephp/1/

```
<header>Header{width:100%;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

    <nav>nav{max-width:960px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

    </nav>
</header>
<div id="wrapper">wrapper{max-width:960px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

    <div id="tags">tags{max-width:960px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

    </div>
    <article>article{max-width:960px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px; margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

        <div id="post_info">post_info{max-width:660px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

        </div>
        <div id="post_content">post_content{max-width:660px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

        </div>
        <div id="text_divider">text_divider{max-width:670px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

        </div>
    </article>
    <div id="pagination">pagination{max-width:680px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>

    </div>
    <footer>footer{} <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vehicula pretium turpis, eu fringilla ante mattis id. Quisque congue fermentum mauris id feugiat. Aliquam nibh nibh, laoreet a metus eu, ornare volutpat augue. Duis ante turpis, pharetra eget hendrerit eget, congue eget diam. Sed efficitur dolor vel sodales rutrum. Quisque viverra vitae dui pulvinar bibendum. Sed consectetur nibh vel accumsan ultricies. Nam dignissim interdum ultricies. Fusce elementum non turpis nec ultricies.</span>
    </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot to say this is a responsive website. On mobile site it is like the demonstration I gave. I want it to be moved when using media query. Is it possible?

Comment: Use bootstrap. You won't need to add custom css to make it responsive

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But I want to have some exercise. So better if I can write CSS by myself

Answer (score 0):

Ok, move the entire `<div id="tags"></div>`

Just above `<article>`

```
<div id="wrapper">
    wrapper{max-width:960px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;}      <span>Lorem ipsum ...</span>
    <div id="tags">
        tags{max-width:960px;border: 1px solid;padding: 20px;margin: 20px auto;}    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor ...</span>
    </div>
    <article> 
    <!-- code.. -->
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I forgot to say this is a responsive website. On mobile site it is like the demonstration I gave. I want it to be moved when using media query. Is it possible?